# zfcuser registration process is not working

Tags: zend-framework2, zfcuser

I am learning Zend Framework(2.0), I have downloaded the skeleton application and installed the zfcuser. When I tried with registration process but it just reloads the nothing else.
Database connection is working fine as I have tried album module from quick start tutorial and it is working fine.

Please guide, thanks in advance.

Environment: Apache 2.0, Zendframework 2.0, PHP 5.3.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this:

http://blog.evan.pro/getting-started-with-the-zf2-skeleton-and-zfcuser

simple to follow to get up and running